# RelativeLayout.BELOW not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I try to make view under other view progmaly my problem is that its dont seems to work.
The views not going below they view in my code.
The `firstText` and `secondText` arent going under the ID's i put.
Thank for helping :)

```
public void setHelper() {

linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.checkHelp1);
linear2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);

firstText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
secondText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

linear1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
linear2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.checkNeedHelp);
            firstText.setLayoutParams(lp2);

            lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.addNewExercise);
            lp2.setMargins(0, 25, 0, 0);
            secondText.setLayoutParams(lp2);

}
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editRoutine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/routines"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="add new routine"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout2"
        android:text="Routine exercsies" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/routineExercises"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/deleteExerciseFromRoutine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/routineExercises"
        android:text="Choose exercise to add to selected routine" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/exerciseForRoutine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addExercisesToRoutine" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addExercisesToRoutine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/exerciseForRoutine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addNewRoutine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/routines"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deleteExerciseFromRoutine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/close" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/deleteExerciseFromRoutine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/removeRoutine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/routines"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/routineExercises"
        android:src="@drawable/close" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Edit Routines"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/checkHelp1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkNeedHelp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Manage routines"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add new routines or delete one from the list" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editRoutine"
        android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Routine exercies"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add exercies to selected routine or delete one" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeLayOut2"
        android:layout_width="110sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goHomePage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="home page"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goCalendar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calendar"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goLive"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="live workout"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goToday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Today log"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goProgram"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Program plan"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goPersonal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pesonal detials"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goWorkout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set workout"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkHelp1"
        android:text="Routines" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/routines"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/removeRoutine" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkNeedHelp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
        android:text="Need help?"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <com.example.workoutlog.VerticalTextView
                android:id="@+id/swipeImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/swipeLayOut2"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:text="swipe right"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Layouts` process their children in a top down fashion so any `layout_above`, `layout_below` etc must refer to a view physically above it in the layout file.

So before using layout_below put the xml of relevant view.

An example is below:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contribution_amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="72sp"
            android:text="77"
            tools:text="77"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/contribution_amount"
            android:paddingTop="12sp"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:text="$"
            tools:text="$"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that the TextView with layout_toStartOf references a view that has been defined before itself. If I had put the TextView with the layout_toStartOf element before the contribution_amount TextView the layout would not work.

Comment: I dont get you answer. i user BELOW only on physical view. You can copy my XML code and see.

Comment: i meant put the a view of id above the other view, where you are using that id as below

Comment: have you understood what i told?

Comment: He is saying that you must have defined the view are referencing in your layout first.